# Flutter custom font not getting applied

Tags: flutter, custom-font

Am trying to set a custom font to my `Text` in `Flutter`. I have tried everything I know but it didn't work. Is this a bug or something?

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/onboarding1.png
    - assets/images/onboarding2.png
    - assets/images/onboarding3.png
  fonts:
    - family: Gilroy
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/gilroy_extrabold.otf
```

**Dart File**

```
SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                            Text(
                              'Connect with Mentors',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Gilroy',
                                fontSize: 35.0,
                              ),
                            ),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the flutter website: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts

**Folder Structure:**

```
your_app/
  fonts/
    Raleway-Regular.ttf
    Raleway-Italic.ttf
    RobotoMono-Regular.ttf
    RobotoMono-Bold.ttf
```

**Declare in pubspec.yaml:**

```
flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: Raleway
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
    - family: RobotoMono
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

You are using asset prefix while declaring, I think it's the problem !

Comment: What about if we're building for web? Seems like for hosted web you have to have the fonts in a web/assets folder.

Comment: @user5269602 when building/compiling for the web it also takes the font from the folder.

Comment: @naveen-avidi Even with - asset: fonts/IndieFlower-Regular.ttf , I got the same issue