# Flutter custom font doesn't change

Tags: flutter

I tried to use a custom font for my AppBar, but it didn't change. I tried with two different fonts, RobotoMono and DancingScript, but nothing, the app did't change the font. I tried to unistall the app from the virtual phone too, too create another virtual device, but nothing. That's my main.dart :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'background_image_task-9.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Blumax',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'Dancing', 
        primarySwatch: myColour
      ),
      home: BackgroundImage(
        ),
    );
  }
}

const MaterialColor myColour = const MaterialColor(
  0xFF0009FF,
  const <int, Color>{
    50: const Color(0xFF0009FF),
    100: const Color(0xFF0009FF),
    200: const Color(0xFF0009FF),
    300: const Color(0xFF0009FF),
    400: const Color(0xFF0009FF),
    500: const Color(0xFF0009FF),
    600: const Color(0xFF0009FF),
    700: const Color(0xFF0009FF),
    800: const Color(0xFF0009FF),
    900: const Color(0xFF0009FF),
  },
);
```

This is where i use the custom font, background_image_task-9.dart :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BackgroundImage extends StatelessWidget{
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          title: Text('Blumax', style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            fontFamily: 'RobotoMono',
            fontSize: 40
          ),),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage("assets/blumax.jpg"), fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

And that's my pubspec.yaml :

```
name: iphone_prj
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  english_words: ^3.1.0

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/


  uses-material-design: true
fonts:
  - family: RobotoMono
    fonts:
      - asset: assets/fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf
  - family: DancingScript
    fonts:
      - asset: assets/fonts/DancingScript-Bold.ttf
        weight: 300
```

Comment: have you try to `flutter_clean` ?

Comment: in the terminal?

Comment: yep in the terminal

Comment: and i think , `fonts` need more space. Make it in line with `assets`

Comment: No change with flutter clean. And no, fonts dont need more space, i got compile error with more space, in the official documentation is like mine

Comment: https://ibb.co/mHtfCCD check my screenshot if it is still not working, try to run `flutter packages get`

Comment: I think @MyNameIs is right, but you need to add space not only for `fonts`, but also for it children (`family`, ...)

Comment: Now work, just add 1 more indent to fonts and family, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add your font-family name properly in your main ThemeData as per pubspec.yaml file

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Blumax',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'DancingScript', 
        primarySwatch: myColour
      ),
      home: BackgroundImage(
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem in your case is your font-family name is **DancingScript** and your providing it in the ThemeData as **Dancing**. So it will not effect to your app fonts.

Also, in your BackgroundImage class you have added **RobotoMono** font. But, the **"fontWeight: FontWeight.w500"** you have added is not matching as per your pubspec.yaml as you have added there **RobotoMono-Bold** fonts.

So, by matching your font names and font style will effect your app fonts as per your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

**There can be many reasons that avoid changing font in flutter :**

1- Notice that the **pubsec.yaml** file is Space sensitive , It means that you need to use 2 or 4 spaces for declaring blocks. That's why you have to use indentation before declaring fonts. you can see the correct example in the snippet below:

```
flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: Raleway
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
    - family: RobotoMono
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

2- As the document  mentioned the **Folder Structure** should be like :

```
awesome_app/
  fonts/
    Raleway-Regular.ttf
    Raleway-Italic.ttf
    RobotoMono-Regular.ttf
    RobotoMono-Bold.ttf
```

3- Add your font-family name correctly in your main ThemeData as per pubspec.yaml file:

```
 MaterialApp(
 title: 'Custom Fonts',
 // Set Raleway as the default app font.
 theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
 home: MyHomePage(),);
```

Answer (score 0):

your using asset prefix while declaring fonts in pubspec.yaml

Here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/59113335/5557479